# Cocos2d : adding zoom in zoom out in a game

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game like a mario in cocos 2d, It has got left , right button and jump button.

I want to zoom the screen little bit when left or right button pressed and  revert back to normal when button released.

Any ideas to implement this in cocos 2d?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cocos2D-iPhone-Extensions CCLayerPanZoom.m

Comment: any documentation or tutorial link for this class ?

Comment: @Vishnu, hey download cocos2d extension sdk and run zoom layer sample. Link:http://is.gd/vHU0u9